# File not found when i try to add to array list

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, input, output

i trying to add to array list but the eclipse cant find the .txt file

```
public void readData(String filename) {
 
    try{
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Where Are Yew\\eclipse-workspace\\A2\\bin\\input.txt");
        FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(filereader);
        String line;
        while(true) {
           line=br.readLine();
           if(line==null)
               break;
           String[] words=line.split("\\s");
```

Comment: Please share your whole code, as well as the precise error message you are getting.

Comment: Hi @akortex , thanks for your feedback, my whole code consider of various file , you can download it from here :  https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a93d491b9b214e5ba7de9dfdc255beb820210730085524/22a9e88dfb87ecfe49a2c1edb0d4652e20210730085553/e191ff , Basically i try to run a client that display student result , but one of the option in the menu "add student data to array list i cant seems to get eclipse to read the .txt file and save the output to .csv file , i not sure what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

A more appropriate way to play this method might be to do something like this:

```
public void readData(String filename) {
    // 'Try With Resources' is use here to auto-close reader. 
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();  // Trim leading/trailing whitespaces, etc.
            // Skip past blank data lines
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            // Do whatever you want to do with the read in data line.
            String[] words = line.split("\\s+");    
        }
    }
    /* Catch and display any IO Exception. If the file 
       can't be found then this will tell you. Perhaps
       you don't have permission to access it... it 
       would tell you that too. Don't ignore Exceptions. */
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger("readData() Method Error!").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You@DevilsHnd for your input, learn something new about Java today.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
```

is what you need as your input file contains irregular spacing. I strongly recommend you use tab-separated files instead of space-separated ones as your fields can then have spaces where they are needed

Comment: Thank You@g00se for your input and explanation.

Comment: A pleasure. Please upvote and accept the answer